# serverspec test fails for listening port

Tags: serverspec

I got a kitchen-ansible test that runs serverspec as a verifier. The test runs on two containers. One running with Amazon Linux 1 and the other Amazon Linux 2. The Ansible code installs a Keycloak server which listens on the ports 8080 and 8443.

In the Amazon Linux 1 container, everything's fine and the serverspec reports the ports to be listening.

In the Amazon Linux 2 container, the installation also ends without any errors but serverspec fails to report the ports not be listening. As I found out Serverspec is wrong.
After logging into the container running `netstat -tulpen |grep LISTEN` it shows the ports to be listening. Serverspec is checking with ss command: `/bin/sh -c ss\ -tunl\ \|\ grep\ -E\ --\ :8443\\\`
So I logged in to the Amazon Linux 1 container for checking the output of the ss command there and it showed no listening on both ports.

So has anyone a clue why the serverspec succeeds on Amazon Linux 1 and fails on Amazon Linux 2 despite in both containers the ss command is reporting no ports to be listened on?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was, that the ports aren't bind quickly enough. Serverspec starts to check, when the service hasn't been started completely. Logging in to the container takes more time, so the service is started successful and the ports are bound.